# Apply style with different color

Tags: android, android-view

[image]

How to apply style and color with first half words one color and other half worlds other colors like above image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Spannable str = "AIRTEL"; 

            str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="28dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        />


TextView tvText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvText);
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("AIRTEL");        

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, 3,   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tvText.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

This may help you.